# Facescroll script with custom/minimized jquery.iu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want to use facebook style scroll script on my site. i found **Facescroll** script on dynamicdrive; but it uses 200kb jquery.ui... 
[dynamicdrive facescroll script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/)

i dont want my site to load 200kb jquery.iu.js for only this scrolling script (loading it from ajax.googleapis.com is not a solution i think)..

may i simplfy or re-write this **jquery.ui.min.js** for only this scripts need?

Comment: You can probably just figure out which parts of jQuery UI it uses and only download those components into the jQuery UI script which would reduce its size: http://jqueryui.com/download/ With only the core components you're only looking at about 19KB.

Comment: so, how can i know which components does this script use?

Comment: You could look at the helpful comment in the script maybe? http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/facescroll.js

Comment: thank you so much.. its now 33kb :)